# Web Application Database or Maps for performance

Tags: java, mysql, database, multithreading, performance

I want to know whether it is useful to use ConcurrentHashMaps for user data. I have the user data saved in a mysql database and retrieve them when a user logs in (or someone edits the user). Every time when the user goes on another page, these user data will be refreshed. Should I use a map and save changes from my application there while having a database in background or should I directly download it from the db. I want to make the application as performant as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a *cache*. Suppose the calls to the database cost a lot because there is a lot of info to load, or the query that is used to extract the data is complex and requires a lot of time. Here comes in play the cache data structure. It is basically an in memory storage, which is really faster w.r.t querying the database, because indeed, it is already loaded in memory.

The process of filling the cache takes the same time as querying the db for the data (generally more but in the same order). So it makes sense to use caches only if it brings benefit in time. There is a compromise though, *speed* vs *freshness* of data. Depending on your use-case you must find the right compromise between those two, and you shall afterwards find out if it is really convenient.

As you describe it, i.e user updates that needs to be saved and displayed, using a cache seems a bit an overkill IMO, unless you have lot of registered users, and so many of those are using the system simultaneously. If you decide to use it keep in mind of some concurrency issues that may rise. Concurrent hash maps saves you from many hazards but with performance compromise.

Answer (score 0):

If the performance is the priority I think you should keep the logged users in memory.

That way, the read requests would be fast as you would not need to query the database. However, you would need to update the map if any of the logged users would be somehow edited.

Answer (score 0):

A human cannot tell the difference between a 1ms delay and a 50ms delay.  So it is overkill to optimize beyond "good enough".

MySQL already does a flavor of caching; your addition of another cache may actually slow down the response time.